# What is that loop you hold on to when you ride a bus/subway?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What is that loop you hold on to when you ride a bus/subway?

Is it called a loop of some sort? Or handle? In the picture below, an invisible... ?

[image]

Comment: You mean *straps*?

Comment: Yes, _straps_. One who holds on to them is called a _straphanger_.

Comment: In Jaguar cars, the strap above the door is referred to in the owners manual as a _Dowager strap_. (circa 1986)

Comment: @Frank Seems Jaguar is the only one that calls them so (for some unknown but very interesting reason).

Comment: @Kris - My guess is that it's because the demographic that Jaguar was targeting back then consisted largely of people who were wealthy, status-conscious and mostly elderly.

Comment: @ErikKowal Excuse me, I'll have you know I rarely had a dowager in the back seat of my Jag, but when the occasion arose those straps sure kept them secure. ;)

Comment: @Frank - Yes, those straps can be used for many purposes. Hopefully the driver's handbook included full instructions.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Bus-strap](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bus-strap%22&tbm=isch)*

[image]
"Here is a bus driver grabbing onto typical straps"

*[Grab/ Grab Handle](http://jswxzkm.en.ec21.com/City_Bus_Plastic_Grab_Handle--7696672_7696673.html)*

[image]
"City Bus Plastic Grab Handle"

Comment: Bus straps are used on the subway??

Comment: "Strap" is by-far the most common term used in New York, to the point that the community activists supporting users of NYC's public transportation are known as *the Straphangers*.

Comment: That guy is enjoying the straps way too much.

Comment: @KRyan: But is *"straps"* the most common term because the community activists are known as *"the Straphangers"*, or the other way around?

Answer (score 5):

The [standing passenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_passenger) has his own page.

> hanging strap: a strap suspended from the ceiling with a handle provided for standing passengers to hold on to
>
> handrails: running horizontally along the ceiling
>
> stanchions: vertical poles
>
> grab rails: smaller hand rails attached to seats, doors and doorways

And whether it is a train, subway car, bus, or car I would probably just call them *oh-shit handles*.

Comment: In the *Enchanted Typewriter* the kings and queens come from Hades and they were having a ball in a trolley car. The author calls them *straps* as well. NB: I just commented on the wrong comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: I've got a concern with this Wikipedia page. Is handrail really only a horizontal bar? Can't I call a vertical one a handrail? I'm also not sure about this `stanchion` term. When you look it up on Google Images, you won't find any images with long bars used to hold on to.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a [handgrip](http://www.ec21.com/offer_detail/Sell_City_Bus_hand_Grip--4725205.html) in some cities, but the terms [bus handle, bus pull handle, bus pull ring, city bus handle](http://handle4bus.en.ec21.com/) are also in use.

Comment: The pull handles and pull rings are different things. These signal the driver that a passenger wants off at the next stop.

Comment: @ Oldcat,  I thought so too but It was included in the term search 'bus handle'